# python: changes to my copy variable affect the original variable

Tags: python

I've got a list that I create a copy of in order to do some manipulations while still keeping the original list. However, when I set `copy_list` equal to `org_list`, they become the same thing, and if I change `copy_list`, `org_list` changes too. For example:

```
org_list = ['y', 'c', 'gdp', 'cap']

copy_list = org_list

copy_list.append('hum')

print(copy_list)
print(org_list)
```

returns

```
['y', 'c', 'gdp', 'cap', 'hum']
['y', 'c', 'gdp', 'cap', 'hum']
```

I don't know too much about what is actually going on but it looks like `org_list` is actually  passing itself to `copy_list` so that they are actually the same thing.

Is there a way to make an independent copy of org_list without doing something clumsy like:

```
copy_list = []
for i in org_list:
    copy_list.append(i)
```

I say this because I have the same problem with other types of variables, for example a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Assignments in Python *do not* create new objects - an assignment merely establishes a binding between a [variable] name and an object. That should explain everything, without talking about "references".

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That is because in python setting a variable actually sets a reference to the variable. Almost every person learning python encounters this at some point. The solution is simply to copy the list:

```
copy_list = org_list[:]
```

Comment: I just spend the past 3 hours trying to debug my program... I thought I was going mad. This was the most infuriating bug I have EVER ran into. Wow...

Comment: @43.52.4D. Only it's not a bug :-)

Comment: @yuvi what if its a two dimensional array?

Comment: @SachinSingh then you need to loop-copy, because a matrix is actually a list of references. Copying that list does not mean copying the references as well (which makes sense). Though that's not a very common situation (I can't think of any reason why you'd ever need to do it to be honest)

Comment: If you have a list of objects, you need to do a "Deep Copy" instead: `import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)`

Comment: you can use copy method for copy data  : ->      copy_list = org_list.copy()

Answer (score 23):

When you write

```
org_list = ['y', 'c', 'gdp', 'cap']
```

you create the list object, and give it the name "org_list".

Then when you do

```
copy_list = org_list
```

you just mean, "the name copy_list refers to the same object as org_list does".

If your list only contains immutable types, then you can create a copy by

```
copy_list = list(org_list)
```

But note that this is only valid if the list objects are immutable, because it creates a SHALLOW copy, i.e. the list is copied, but every element on the list is not duplicated.

If you have i.e. a list of lists and want EVERYTHING to be duplicated, you need to perform a DEEP copy:

```
import copy
org_list = ['y', 'c', ['gdp', 'rtd'], 'cap']
copy_list = copy.deepcopy(org_list)
```

Comment: In other words, if you don't deep copy you will end up with: copy_list = ['y','c',org_list[2],'cap']

Answer (score 19):

This is just copying the reference

```
copy_list = org_list
```

you should use

```
copy_list = org_list[:]    # make a slice that is the whole list
```

or

```
copy_list = list(org_list)
```

Comment: what if its a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @SachinSingh, Then you need to also copy each sublist. You should probably checkout deepcopy. https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: thanks. i saw that. But is there is another way by which i can do that i mean without using deepcopy?

Comment: Python 3.3+ provides a copy method: `copy_list = org_list.copy()`

Answer (score 11):

Variable names in python are references to the original. To actually make a copy, you need to be [explicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
import copy

copy_list = copy.copy(org_list)
```

Comment: what if its a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @SachinSingh you can use `firstList = copy.deepcopy(secondList)`

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot!! I have a 2 dimensional array and you solved my issue