# viariable changes but no update to it made

Tags: python

I'm trying to flip an image (matrix with RGB values) taken with opencv in Python by switching the columns on the top and bottom:

```
cv2.imshow('Image',image)
temp = image[0]
row,col,number = image.shape
for i in range (0,col/2) :
        temp = image[i] 
        image[i] = image[col-i-1]
        image[col-i-1] = temp
```

For some reason, `temp` changes to `image[col-i-1]` after executing `image[i] = image[dol-i-1]`.

I printed the first values of each column to see what changed and it showed this:

```
temp
[ 74 63 167]  (old) 
[ 85 69 177]  (new)
image[i]
[ 85 69 177]  (old)
[ 77 66 170]  (new)
temp
[ 77 66 170]  (old)
[ 77 66 170]  (new)
image[col-i-1]
[ 77 66 170]  (old)
[ 77 66 170]  (new)
```

So why does `temp` change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the temporary variable seems to change is because in Python, you're not making a *deep* copy when you assign

```
temp = image[i]
```

Instead, you're "binding" a new name to the same object. This means that `temp` simply points to the same underlying data structure that `image[i]` is also pointing to. When you next make an update to `image[i]`, that change will also be reflected in the `temp` variable.

An easy example that shows the same behaviour is this one:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a[2] = 0
>>> a  # as expected
[1, 2, 0]
>>> b  # python gotcha
[1, 2, 0]
```

It's a common pitfall for people who are new to Python, as evidenced from the dozens of [related SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable).