# Python managing multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am doing some very basic operations with Python (3.6, but also tested in Python 2.11 - behavior is the same) and dictionaries. Here is the code sample:

```
max_values = dict()
min_values = dict()

initial_values = {"stat": 2, "value": 5.5}

max_values["zzz"] = initial_values
min_values["zzz"] = initial_values
```

So far so good, when I print those dictionaries:

```
for key, value in max_values.items():
    print("[%s] Key [%s] -> Value [%s]" % ("max_values", key, value))

for key, value in min_values.items():
    print("[%s] Key [%s] -> Value [%s]" % ("min_values", key, value))
```

I get my expected results:

```
[max_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 5.5}]
[min_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 5.5}]
```

But if I attempt to modify with the values, for example:

```
min_values["zzz"]["value"] = 1.0
```

And do the same print again, I get:

```
[max_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 1.0}]
[min_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 1.0}]
```

Question is: Why was the `max_values` dictionary changed? I have only modified `min_values`, but this new key assignment for `min_value` dictionary also modified `max_values`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Assingment **_does not copy_**. Both of the dictionaries key's have a reference to the same dictionary. You need to explicitly tell Python to make a copy of `initial_values` for both keys.

Comment: `max_values["zzz"] = dict(initial_values)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Or `max_values["zzz"] = initial_values.copy()`.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable) would work. It's not an exact duplicate, but it explains what assignment does in Python.

Comment: @ChristianDean you are correct, it's intended functionality in Python (and I assume in other languages as well). For anyone else willing to read a bit more about the difference between assignment and copying this link can help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one dict `initial_values` and both of your dict are refers to the same dict `initial_values`. You have to copy this dict to get another dict.

Try to:

```
max_values["zzz"] = initial_values
min_values["zzz"] = dict(initial_values)
```

or:

```
max_values["zzz"] = initial_values
min_values["zzz"] = initial_values.copy()
```

And now this constructions:

```
min_values["zzz"]["value"] = 1.0

for key, value in max_values.items():
    print("[%s] Key [%s] -> Value [%s]" % ("max_values", key, value))

for key, value in min_values.items():
    print("[%s] Key [%s] -> Value [%s]" % ("min_values", key, value))
```

Get expected result:

```
[max_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 5.5}]
[min_values] Key [zzz] -> Value [{'stat': 2, 'value': 1.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the max_values and min_values are linked together. That is, they are both referencing initial_values. So if you change one you change the other. One solution would be to use deepcopy.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see from the graph, `Max_value` and `Min_value` reference to `Initial_value` , which means `Max_value` and `Min_value` link to the address where you create initial_value dictionary. Once you update the value inside of the initial_val, it will also show in both  `Max_value` and `Min_value`.

To avoid this problem, you can use `from copy import deepcopy.`

```
my_dict = {'1': 1, '1': 2}
new_dict= deepcopy(my_dict)
```

In this way, it creates a new instance for your old dictionary.

Comment: That was the case! Thanks for the visual representation.

Answer (score -2):

Because you gave both of the values same dictionary just look at the first two lines of your code.