# changing values in copied list

Tags: python, list

I have a question about how changing values in copied(?) lists can affect the original one.

An Example:

```
a = [1, 2, [3,4]]
b = list(a)

b.append(100)
b 
[1,2,[3,4],100]
a 
[1,2,[3,4]] 

b[2][0] = -100
b 
[1,2,[-100,4],100] 
a
[1,2,[-100,4]] 

b[0] = 3
b 
[3,2,[-100,4],100] and
a
[1,2,[-100,4]]
```

Why sometimes changing or adding values on `list(b)` doesn't affect `list(a)` and sometimes it does affect `list(a)`?

Comment: first of all format your question. I, personally, can't understand what your code is doing.

Comment: This is just copying the reference. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable

Comment: `list(a)` or `a[:]` returns a shallow copy, i.e only the outer container changes(inner objects remain the same)

Comment: use `copy.deepcopy(a)`