# Changing the copy, changing the original

Tags: python, list

I'm a novice at python, and I've just started to learn about lists. 
I have tried to make a copy of different kind of lists and then changing the copy. The last case actually changes the list of the original when changing the copy. I really can't understand why this is happening:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
c=a[:]
c[2]=100
print("a=", a)
```

Which gives me a= [1,2,3,4]

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
c=a[:]
c[1]=[3,100]
print("a=", a)
```

which gives me a=[[1,2],[3,4]]

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
c=a[:]
c[1][1]=100 
print("a=", a)
```

Which changes a, and gives me a=[[1,2],[3,100]].

Can anyone explain to me, why a is changed when changing the copy of a in the last case?

Comment: The slice is a *shallow* copy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19952361/1219006 @Roberto tells you to use `copy.deepcopy`