# How to properly dereference if copying a part of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reference, copy

In my analysis script I noticed some weird behaviour (guess it's intended though) with the copying of arrays in Python. If I have a 2D-array `A`, create another array `B` with entries from `A` and then normalize `B` with the length of `A`'s first dimension, the entries in `A` change in a strange way. I can reproduce the problem with the following code:

```py
foo = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
startIndex = 1
print(foo)
for it, i in enumerate(foo):
    if not it:
        sum = i[startIndex:]
    else:
        sum += i[startIndex:]
print(foo)
sum /= foo.shape[0]
print(foo)
```

The output is:

```py
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [7. 8. 9.]]
[[ 1. 15. 18.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9.]]
[[1. 5. 6.]
 [4. 5. 6.]
 [7. 8. 9.]]
```

The shape of the array doesn't matter but this 3x3 form shows it quite good. I guess that `sum = i[startIndex:]` somehow sets a reference to the last two entries of `foo[0]` and changes to `sum` also effect those entries - but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable) I guessed I would get a copy instead of the reference. What is the proper way to get a copy of only a part of the array?

Comment: Your link is talking about `list` objects, which will create copies if you slice. Slicing for `numpy.ndarray` objects, however, creates *views*

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a note on array construction.  An array has basic information like `shape`, `dtype` and `strides`, and a 1d `data buffer`, where the actual values are stored.

A copy would be a new array object, with its own values.

A view is a new array object, with its own `shape`,etc, but it shares the `data buffer` with the source array.  As an efficiency measure, `numpy` tries to make a view where possible.  Many operations do this, such as `reshape` and `transpose`.  Indexing can also make a view.  `basic indexing` with a scalar or slice makes a view, `advanced indexing` with lists, masks or arrays makes a copy.

`X.copy()` is one way of forcing a copy.  `np.array(X)` also makes a copy - if using its default `copy` parameter.

```
In [113]: foo = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
```

Iteration on a 2d array, as you do, selects successive 'rows', each a view:

```
In [114]: for row in foo: 
     ...:     row[1] += 10     # modify the 2nd element of the row
     ...:                                                                                        
In [115]: foo                                                                                    
Out[115]: 
array([[ 1., 12.,  3.],
       [ 4., 15.,  6.],
       [ 7., 18.,  9.]])
```

Selecting the row by scalar index does the same thing:

```
In [116]: foo[0]                                                                                 
Out[116]: array([ 1., 12.,  3.])
In [117]: foo[0][1:]-=10                                                                         
In [118]: foo                                                                                    
Out[118]: 
array([[ 1.,  2., -7.],
       [ 4., 15.,  6.],
       [ 7., 18.,  9.]])
In [119]: foo[0,1:]                                                                              
Out[119]: array([ 2., -7.])
```

So becoming familiar as to when you get a view and when a copy is an important part of learning `numpy`.

So using `copy` to make a copy of the 1st row:

```
In [124]: foo = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])                                                                                             
In [126]: sum = foo[0,1:].copy() 
     ...: for row in foo[1:]:     # iterate on a slice (skips 1st row)
     ...:     sum += row[1:]      # select a slice of row (skips 1st element)                                            
In [127]: foo                # no change                                                                    
Out[127]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
In [128]: sum                                                                                    
Out[128]: array([15., 18.])
```

But we could also take this sum without iteration:

```
In [129]: foo[:, 1:].sum(axis=0)   # select slice of columns, sum across rows                                                                 
Out[129]: array([15., 18.])
```

A better way to write [126] iteration (and probably close to what `sum` implements in compiled code):

```
In [200]: res = np.zeros(2, float)                                                               
In [201]: for row in foo: 
     ...:     res += row[1:] 
     ...:                                                                                        
In [202]: res                                                                                    
Out[202]: array([15., 18.])
```

Comment: I assume ```In [129]``` creates a copy because it is some kind of advanced indexing, correct?

Comment: `foo[:, 1:]` is `view` (indexing with slices), but the `sum` method isn't modifying any values.  It is compiled code.  Internally it does use some sort of buffer to accumulate values, but that buffer is probably initialized as a new `zeros` array.  I added an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy by value using the `np.array` constructor:

```py
for it, i in enumerate(foo):
    if not it:
        s = np.array(i[startIndex:])
    else:
        s += i[startIndex:]
```

Note that I've changed the name of the variable to avoid shadowing the built-in `sum` function.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer! I can't upvote it currently, maybe in the future.