# Why a value is wrongly given to an array?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am new to python and programming. Sadly, I got a problem working on a easy task very soon and could not find a answer to this. In the following, I make up a short example:

```
a0=np.ones(10);
a1=a0;
a2=a0;
sum1=3;
sum2=2;
a1[0]=sum1;
a2[0]=sum2;
print(a1)
```

However, the first element of the array a1 is 2 instead of 3. Would someone like to explain to me why and additionally show me a proper way to fulfill this?  In the real task, I will run loops for different time periods. Within each loop, I generate different values such as mean, median, and sum. (like sum1 and sum2 in the short sample) These values are given to the arrays (like a1 and a2) with a length already defined.
By the way, I use JupyterLab to run python 3.

Comment: Why are you using semicolons at the end of each line? Python does not require semicolons.

Comment: In addition to the issue of semicolons, why is there no whitespace in your code? _In the following, I make up a short example_ It might also be worth sharing your entire program, alongside the example.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19951816/11301900, which itself is marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/11301900.

Comment: @nerdguy I do not add semicolons in my codes when I program, but I am not sure whether it is a correct way to do so. Before I posted the question, I found some other posted questions with sample codes ending with semicolons, which I thought might be better, so I just followed. Thank you for your comment, and now I know what is standard.

Comment: @AMC You are right that the question is duplicated. It is also regarding reference which I don't know before. Thank you for the reference and I solve the problem by copying the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign `a1=a0`, it means that array `a1` refers to the referent of `a0`. In other words, you bind `a0` to the same value as `a1`.

You will see the change in all variables pointing to the same list.

To avoid this, you should copy the array `a0`, so they do not refer each other:

```
a0=np.ones(10)
a1=a0.copy()
a2=a0.copy()
sum1=3
sum2=2
a1[0]=sum1
a2[0]=sum2
print(a0)
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

Outputs as:

```
a0 : array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
a1 : array([3., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
a2 : array([2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```