# Python 3 comparing list variables

Tags: python, pointers

I want to make list `b` equal to list `a`, and then change `b` without influencing a.

```
a = "1234"
b = ""
a = list(a)
b = a
```

When I `print(a)` after changing `b`, `a` changes as well.
Although in the code below, I don't get this problem, meaning whatever change I make to variable `b`, `a` will stay independent.

```
a = "1234"
b = ""
a = list(a)
b = list(a)
```

I am looking for an explanation on what happened behind the scenes and why the second code example worked.

Comment: Names (variables) are references to objects in Python. If you do `b = a` you will make `b` reference to the same object `a` references to. If you want to make a shallow copy of a list, just use `b = a[:]`

Comment: To complete @KlausD. 's comment, you can also copy the list with `b = a.copy()` (works the same with dictionaries btw)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable

Because of reference type

Comment: you can read more about it with the buzzwords **view vs. copy python**. Also keep in mind that if you have e.g. a list of lists `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`  you need to do a deep copy like a.copy(deep=True)

Comment: @Berger Thank you for your response and reference for further reading :)  I have tried to .copy()  a list of lists and it seems to work fine (checked for id() and they are different too). Also, .copy(deep=True)  produced the following error: "TypeError: copy() takes no keyword arguments" so I am a bit confused as to what was your point.

Comment: @Davisko sorry, `.copy(deep=True)` was for DataFrames, I just saw for them it's on default set to True. Now to lists again: What I mean is the following: `a = [[1,2], [3,4]]` now do `b = a.copy()` if you check `id(a) == id(b)` will be false, but `id(a[0]) == id(b[0])` will be true, so you need to do a recursive copy. I just saw for lists you need to `import copy` and do `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign `b=a`, Python assigns by reference, so the variable `b` is just pointing to the same object as `a`. You can confirm this with the `id()` method that prints out the ID of the object:

```
>>> a="1234"
>>> id(a)
2858676454064
>>> b=a
>>> id(b)
2858676454064
```

When you do `b = list(a)`, the `list()` method returns a new list.

```
>>> a = list(a)
>>> id(a)
2858676458880
>>> b = list(a)
>>> id(b)
2858676458944
```

After `a = list(a)`, the `a` object is no longer the same as the `a` previously (2858676454064).