# Issue while finding sum of rows of matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I was trying to implement a matrix using lists in Python. I understand that numpy would be more suitable for the job, but I wanted to try it with lists.
Here is the code:

```
def input_array():                  #Take the list elements as input from user
    array = []
    row = input("Enter the num of rows: ")
    col = input("Enter the num of cols: ")
    for i in range(int(row)):
        arr = []
        for j in range(int(col)):
            a = eval(input("Enter an element: "))
            arr.append(a)
        array.append(arr)
    print(array)
    return array


def print_array(array):             #Print the list as a matrix
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        for j in range(len(array[i])): 
            print(array[i][j], end = " ") 
        print() 


def getRowSum(array):               #To get the sum of rows and print them beside respective rows
    arr = array[:]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        summ = 0
        for j in arr[i]:
            summ += j
        arr[i].append(summ)
    print_array(arr)


array = input_array()
print_array(array)
getRowSum(array)
print(array)
```

When I run the program, I am facing an odd issue. As per my knowledge, when I am copying a list using `[:]`, then any change to the duplicate list will not affect the original list. But this is not happening in this case. You will see that when I use `print(array)` after executing `getRowSum()`, the list changes even though I worked on a copy of the list in the function.
You would understand it better if you execute the code yourself.
Please tell as to what I am doing wrong and how should I really proceed with it.

Comment: For questions like this, you make it much easier for others if you skip the input function and just hard code the matrix.

Comment: You are correct that you copy the list using [:], however you have a list of lists. See discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
arr.deepcopy()
```

The above method might help you.The `deepcopy()` function will help you to deep copy the list in which the change in the copied list doesn't affect the source list.`arr[:]` will only shallow copy the list which means it copies only the references of the source list.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing a list does not generate a copy of the list; the arrays `array` and `arr` will point to the same memory addresses.

Proceed with the following change to `getRowSum`:

```py
def getRowSum(array):               #To get the sum of rows and print them beside respective rows
    for i in range(len(array)):
        summ = 0
        for j in array[i]:
            print(j, end=" ")
            summ += j
        print(summ)
```

This code is different from the code you have suggested but nonetheless seems to have the functionality outlined in the function comment.

Then, the entire code sample would be:

```py
def input_array():                  #Take the list elements as input from user
    array = []
    row = input("Enter the num of rows: ")
    col = input("Enter the num of cols: ")
    for i in range(int(row)):
        arr = []
        for j in range(int(col)):
            a = eval(input("Enter an element: "))
            arr.append(a)
        array.append(arr)
    print(array)
    return array


def print_array(array):             #Print the list as a matrix
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array[i])):
            print(array[i][j], end = " ")
        print()


def getRowSum(array):               #To get the sum of rows and print them beside respective rows
    for i in range(len(array)):
        summ = 0
        for j in array[i]:
            print(j, end=" ")
            summ += j
        print(summ)


array = input_array()
print_array(array)
getRowSum(array)
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

lists are passed by reference and you are mutating the list.  If you want to construct a new list use a list comprehension with list concatenation

```
def input_array():                  #Take the list elements as input from user
    return [[i*j for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]

array = input_array()
arrays = [row + [sum(row)] for row in input_array()]
print(f"original: {array} \nwith totals:{arrays}")
```

**output**

```
original: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]] 
withtotals:[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 20], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 30], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 40]]
```