# Elements of list deleted when deleting from a copy of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a code for picking random musics in a list of musics (`music_list`) and adding them to `music_queue`. When I execute this code, all the elements of `music_list` are deleted and I don't understand why.

```py
print("Music list lenght : " + str(len(music_list)))
if len(music_queue) == 0:
    tmp = music_list
    while len(tmp) > 0:
        music_queue.append(tmp.pop(randint(0,len(tmp) - 1)))
print("Music list lenght : " + str(len(music_list)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: changes to my copy variable affect the original variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable) or better yet, the duplicate from that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent

Comment: try ```tmp = music_list.copy()``` instead. For lists, the "=" operator makes a copy of the same object, and so edits the original when you edit the copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
tmp = music_list
```

to

```
tmp = music_list[:]
```

setting tmp to music list without copying, making a change to one will edit both lists.

This is assuming you don't want to edit `music_list`

The reason of this is because without copying you are referencing the same item in memory:

Without copying:

```
tmp = music_list
```

Memory locations:

```
>>> id(music_list)   
2614314102592
>>> id(tmp)          
2614314102592
```

With copying:

```
tmp = music_list[:]
```

Memory locations:

```
>>> id(music_list)
1782888775808
>>> id(tmp)
1782888775744
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks you I didn't know that this can edit the both at the same time.

Comment: @Redover don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to accept it. It's checked now !