# changes to my duplicate variable modify the original variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, nested-lists

If i define a variable called `puzzle` = [[1, 2, 3]] and then make another variable called `test_puzzle` = `puzzle` when modifying `test_puzzle` the change is applied to `puzzle` as well. I do not want to modify the original `puzzle` variable, is there anyway I am able to create a duplicate without modifying the original value and without the need for loops

I found solutions here:
[python: changes to my copy variable affect the original variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951816/python-changes-to-my-copy-variable-affect-the-original-variable)

and here:
[How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

I tried to do `test_puzzle = puzzle[:]`, `test_puzzle = list(puzzle)` and `test_puzzle = puzzle.copy()` as described but all resulted in the same issue.

````
    puzzle = [[1, 2, 3]]
    test_puzzle = puzzle
    test_puzzle[0][1] = 7
    print(puzzle)
    print(test_puzzle)```
````

```
-> [[1, 7, 3]]
-> [[1, 7, 3]]
```

Comment: you must copy the inner list as well, e.g. `test_puzzle = [puzzle[0][:]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[:]` or `copy` doesn't copy the list inside the outer list

So you're changing the same object, but you can use `deepcopy` to fix that, or simple copy the list inside:

```
from copy import deepcopy

puzzle = [[1, 2, 3]]
test_puzzle = deepcopy(puzzle)
# or
# test_puzzle = [x[:] for x in test_puzzle]
test_puzzle[0][1] = 7
print(puzzle)
print(test_puzzle)
```

will result in

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 7, 3]]
```